# Bulk Update using Batched Write of Firebase with conditions (using WHERE function)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

The main goal of my system is to update the name of the user who posted on my forum if the authenticated user change or rename his or her account name.

The whole process is error-free but unfortunately, the other user who posted in the forum also updated their name.

So this is the output:

[image: Forum posts]

I try the following:

1. I use the WHERE function in Firebase to filter the post made by the user (log in user itself). I dont know why the whole process is failed.

This is the snippet code.

```
  async updateAll(username) {
    const batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();

    // cUser is the USER ID
    const userRef = this.afs
      .collection('post', (ref) => ref.where('postedById', '==', this.cUser))
      .ref.get();
    (await userRef).forEach((element) => {
      batch.update(element.ref, {
        postedBy: username,
      });
    });

    return batch.commit();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end your query with `.ref.get()`. The `.ref` in there, actually returns the collection on which you run the query, so you end up loading the entire `post` collection.

You'll want to [subscribe to `snapshotChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges) instead, or just use the regular JavaScript SDK to accomplish this (as you're not accessing the UI directly, I typically find that easier):

```
const userRef = firebase.firestore()
  .collection('post').where('postedById', '==', this.cUser).get();
(await userRef).forEach((element) => {
  batch.update(element.ref, {
    postedBy: username,
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my code is okay right now. But I have an additional question what if the user doesn't have post in the forum? Because unfortunately the problem still exists if the user change his or her name without posting in the forum. But all in all the code above works if the user have post in the forum.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the new problem there. If the user doesn't have any posts, the code in my answer won't update any posts, which seems like the correct behavior to me. Isn't that what you want it to do?

Comment: That's what I think sir in the first place but the problem reoccured if the user doesnt have post at all. And yes sir, the code is working perfectly (if the user have a post on the forum).

Comment: sir for the update of the code, I guessed I solved it. If I used `element.exists` the code will run if the user ID is already detected in the post collection. I hope this is good approach of the problem.